# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE. (note I am using model biding)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am using model biding, but I am basically trying to create a form that can edit and update comments. It runs perfectly and even prompts me to edit the form. However, every time I try to update it the POST method is not supported for the root. which is bogus as I did the spoofing correctly, someone help me please.

Here us my CommentsController methods

```
  public function edit($id)
{
    $comment = Commenting::find($id);

    return view('comments.edit', compact('comment'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id, $posts)
{
    $comment = Commenting::find($id);

    $comment->update($request->all());

    $comment->posts_id = $posts;

    return view('post.show', compact('comment'));
}
```

Here is the routing in my web.php

```
Route::get('/posts/comment/{comment}', 'CommentsController@edit')->name('comments.edit')->middleware('auth');

Route::put('/posts/comment/{comment}', 'CommentsController@update')->name('comments.update')->middleware('auth');
```

Here's what I call the link to edit the form in my show.blade

```
 <a href="/posts/comment/{{$comment->id}}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
```

lastly this is my edit.blade file

```
@extends ('layouts.home')

@section ('content')

<div class="card">

<h1> Edit Comment </h1>
  <div class="card-block"> 

    <form method="POST" action="{{route('comments.update', ['comments' => $comment])}}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="body" placeholder="Enter you comment here..." class="form-control"> {{$comment->body}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    @include ('layouts.errors')

  </div>

</div>


@endsection
```

Comment: you can try `PATCH` method instead of PUT method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look your update method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id, $posts)
```

Try to delete the `$posts` variable on `update` function

Comment: can you show how you would do this please? @Ageng D. Prastyawan

Comment: Just change to `public function update(Request $request, $id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

> `{{method_field('put')}}`
>   or
>   `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`

Answer (score 0):

add patch method in blade file:

```
@extends ('layouts.home')
    @section ('content')

    <div class="card">

<h1> Edit Comment </h1>
  <div class="card-block"> 

    <form method="POST" action="{{route('comments.update', ['comments' => $comment])}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">

        <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="body" placeholder="Enter you comment here..." class="form-control"> {{$comment->body}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    @include ('layouts.errors')
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

write post method in route file :

```
Route::post('/posts/comment/{comment}', 'CommentsController@update')->name('comments.update')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route binding is named `comment` not `comments`. This will not generate a URL to your `comments.update` route:

```
route('comments.update', ['comments' => $comment])
```

This will generate a URL to `/posts/comment?comments=3` not `/posts/comment/3`. You want to use the same name as the route parameter so it knows to replace that route parameter:

```
route('comments.update', ['comment' => $comment])
```

Which would generate a URL to `/posts/comment/3`.

Also your controller method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id, $posts)
```

has a `$posts` variable but there is no parameter for that defined for the route, so where does that come from?

If you actually want to use Model Binding, which it would appear you are not, you could use Implicit Bindings by type-hinting a `$comment` argument on that controller method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Comment $comment)
```

as the route pararemeter is named `comment` not `id`.

[Laravel 5.8 - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding)

Comment: how to do what?